# C++ shared_ptr bind map transform segfault

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, bind, shared-ptr

I get a segfault when I run this code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;    

int main(){
  map<int, shared_ptr<int>> container;
  container[5] = make_shared<int>(7);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    vector<shared_ptr<int>> vec(container.size());

    transform(container.begin(), container.end(), vec.begin(),
              bind(&pair<int, shared_ptr<int>>::second, _1));
  }
}
```

I'm compiling with g++ 4.8.2 in c++11 mode.

When I print the use count of the shared_ptr, it seems it gets decremented by 1 each time the for loop runs.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but here is one modification (using C++11 lambdas) that does not crash:         transform(container.begin(), container.end(), vec.begin(),
                  [](const std::pair<int, shared_ptr<int>>& p) { return p.second; });

Comment: type of *container.begin() is not pair<int, shared_ptr<int>>, but pair<const int, shared_ptr<int>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably getting conversions here in `bind(&pair<int, shared_ptr<int>>::second, _1))` because it is `pair<int const, shared_ptr<int>>` what is stored in the map (note `const` on the key type).

Although I am surprised it compiles without an error.

Try any of these:

```
bind(&pair<int const, shared_ptr<int>>::second, _1))
bind(&map<int, shared_ptr<int>>::value_type::second, _1))
bind(&decltype(container)::value_type::second, _1))
```

Answer (score -1):

your problem seem to be that `second` is not a function (it's a member variable), so it cannot be bound with `bind`.

You can either try

```
transform(container.begin(), container.end(), vec.begin(), [](pair<int, shared_ptr<int>> x) { return x.second; });
```

or

```
transform(container.begin(), container.end(), vec.begin(), bind(&_2nd, _1));
```

where you have previously defined

```
shared_ptr<int> _2nd(const pair<int, shared_ptr<int>>& x) { return x.second; }
```

That would work. [Live example at Coliru...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/003fa35a11214f2f)

Comment: Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind: _f - Callable object (function object, pointer to function, reference to function, pointer to member function, or __pointer to data member__) that will be bound to some arguments_